# How can I match www AND non-www in a rewritecond?

Tags: regex, apache, mod-rewrite, rewritemap

I have a rewritemap that has a list of domains to redirect. Currently I have to list www.foo.com and foo.com in the rewrite map. I was wondering if there was a way to have the rewritecond check for both www and non-www in the same line.

```
# Rewrite Map
foo.com file.php
www.foo.com file.php

# modrewrite
RewriteCond ${domainmappings:%{HTTP_HOST}} ^(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %1 !^NOTFOUND$
RewriteRule ^.*$ www.domain.com/%1 [L,R=301]
```

I tried doing things like (www.)%{HTTP_HOST} or ^(www.)%{HTTP_HOST} but no luck.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This should do it:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?(.+)
RewriteCond ${domainmappings:%2} ^(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [L,R=301]
```

The first `RewriteCond` will remove the optional `www.` prefix. The remainder is then used as parameter for the rewrite map in the second `RewriteCond`.

A plain text file rewrite map returns an empty string if no match is found:

> If the key is found, the map-function construct is substituted by *SubstValue*. If the key is not found then it is substituted by *DefaultValue* or by the empty string if no *DefaultValue* was specified.

So if the second condition is fulfilled (note the `^(.+)$`), a match has been found and `%1` will contain the *SubstValue* (in this case `file.php`).

Comment: that doesn't work because i would still have to have entries for www.foo.com and foo.com. I want to only have an entry for foo.com

Comment: Almost there. Both www.foo.com and foo.com go to the right place, but the browser just keeps redirecting until the browser quits. Any idea why?

Comment: ack, got it. It was just going to /page.php instead of domain.com/page.php. I owe you a beer ;)

Answer (score 8):

From a post here

http://www.eukhost.com/forums/f15/simple-rewriterule-set-redirect-domain-6570/

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^xyz.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.xyz.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.xyz.com/test//$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: The problem is I have a lot of domains and can't have xyz.com in the rewritecond or rewriterule.

Comment: also, i want it to match the foo.com version in the rewritemap, so it would have to do something like a substring.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to make the www. part optional with the following:

```
# Rewrite Map
www.foo.com file.php

# modrewrite

# redirect to www domain always
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^.]+\.[^.]+)$
RewriteRule (.*) http://www\.%1/$1 [L,R=301,QSA)

# redirect following the map
RewriteCond ${domainmappings:%{HTTP_HOST}} ^(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %1 !^NOTFOUND$
RewriteRule ^.*$ www.domain.com/%1 [L,R=301]
```

This would first redirect `anything.anything` to `www.anything.anything` and then apply your rule on the next request. Not too knowledgeable with rewrite maps though so no guarantees.

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain.com$ [OR]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.domain.com$

RewriteRule ^ https://www.domain.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Quote: _I was wondering if there was a way to have the rewritecond check for both www and non-www in the same line._